# -1073741819 (0xc0000005) access violation in asp net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

-1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'access violation' Error is casing the aspnet core application to stop functioning and automatically shutting down!! What Could be the Reason?

Answer (score 0):

Currently developing an Application using Asp Net Identity in Asp net core.
 I have used this property for creation of my AspNetUsers table.

```
public DateTime AccountCreationDate 
{
  get { return AccountCreationDate; }

  set 
      { this.AccountCreationDate = DateTime.Now; } 
 }
```

Commenting this property solves my issue.
 I am not sure whether this is the exact cause, but this helped me.
 It would actually be awesome if anyone could add more to this!!

Comment: This property would result in a `StackOverflowException` since it refers to itself ad infinitum.  This code should be in your question.

Comment: You can just do `public DateTime AccountCreationDate { get; private set; }` = DateTime.Now;`